# How to pass PostScript expression to nodesep and offset when using ([...]node) syntax?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

Quoted from `pst-news13.pdf` on page 3:

> The `labelsep` is the first – optional – argument of `\uput`. It is
>   now possible to use the PostScript notation for this length, eg `{! 45
>   sin 3 mul}`. Then the unit which is active when `\uput` is active is
>   used. With a unit the PS notation is not allowed and leads to an
>   error!

If `labelsep` (which is a length key) can accept an RPN expression, why can't `nodesep` and `offset` (which are also length keys) accept RPN expressions?

For the current implementation, `angle` can be expressed in RPN such as `angle={!30 60 add}`.

The following is the MWE for you.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
        \pnode{A}
        \pnode
        [!
            60 cos 3 mul
            60 sin 3 mul
        ](A){B}
        \psline{->}(A)(B)
    \end{pspicture}

%   \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
%       \pnode{A}
%       \psline(A){->}([nodesep=,offset=]A)
%   \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nodesep` and `offset` are a length and must have a unit, at least the current one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
        \pnode{A}
        \pnode
        [!
            60 cos 3 mul
            60 sin 3 mul
        ](A){B}
        \psline{->}(A)(B)
    \end{pspicture}

\bigskip
   \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
       \pnode{A}
       \psline{->}(A)(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} 
         A.x 60 cos 3 mul add 
         A.y 60 sin 3 mul add)
   \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]